# Is it safe to host a website outside public_html

Tags: shared-hosting, web, web-hosting

I am hosting a website where i host my main site in the /home/username/public_html
while i host my blog in /home/username/blog

is it safe that i host the blog in a different folder (/home/username/blog )

Comment: Yes, plenty safe.  If anything it may be more safe than using public_html, because public_html is a known location that a malicious user might try to access/attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about a directory called "public_html" other than that the web server are often configured to look for content there (and some web servers do so by default).

The name is just a convention.

Comment: so hosting a website on different folder doesn't lead to security risks ??

Comment: Names are just names. There is nothing special about them. All else being equal, you can use whatever name you like.